# On my tumblr blog, how do I get the background to be one giant image?

Tags: html, background, blogs, tumblr

This is my tumblr blog:

thestorywithnoending.tumblr.com

the code for the blog is a theme I got here:

http://themes.pouretrebelle.com/lycoris/?download

(just scroll down a bit, the whole code is there)

I want the background image to just be ONE image...

I know I'm not being descriptive enough, so to fruther explain: I want it to be like this:

http://chloescheffe.com/

you see how on that website the background image is.... everything basically. And when you change the size of the webpage, the background image changes accordingly?

how can I do that on my tumblr blog?

THANKS :)

Answer (score 0):

with css. set the height and width of your bg image to 100%. sorry, i'd give you the code but this keyboard doesn't have all the characters of a larger one.
use the background-size css property w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do this two ways using `background-size`. One will stretch the image and one will fill the width properly, but cut off the bottom.

For stretch, add this to your `body` CSS:

```css
body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

For width-fill (this looks better with your current blog), add this to your `body` CSS:

```css
body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```